# Gazebo Crashes when modifying joint velocities

Tags: ros, gazebo, physics

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi All

Just trying to test a plugin to a sdf model of a 7DOF manipulator. In order to test, my i've included the following line in the plugin's OnUpdate() method:

joint1->SetVelocity(0, 0.001);

There are a few other lines in that method but they dont crash the system.
joint1 is a physics::JointPtr and SetVelocity is a method of a joint. I am using rosmake, and it seems to compile fine. However when I go to start GAZEBO I get the following message:

gzserver: /usr/include/boost/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.hpp:418: T* boost::shared_ptr::operator->() const [with T = gazebo::physics::Joint]: Assertion `px != 0' failed.
Aborted (core dumped)

Any suggestions

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/48699/gazebo-crashes-when-modifying-joint-velocities/) by [PeterMilani](https://answers.ros.org/users/3621/petermilani/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1493 on 2012-11-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Okay got to the bottom of this one too!

Very simple, joint1 was not initialized properly.

the name used in physics::model::getJoint was not correct!

it was "joint1" not "Joint1"

cheers

Peter

---

Originally posted by [PeterMilani](https://answers.ros.org/users/3621/petermilani/) with karma: 1493 on 2012-11-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0